# Resolve router error: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MemberListResolver:

Tags: angular

I have an issue when I created Resolver in Angular. When I started application I give an 
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MemberListResolver: (?). error.
Can someone help me?

My Resolver class:

```
Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MemberListResolver implements Resolve<User[]> {
  constructor(private userService: UserService){}

  resolve() {
    return this.userService.getUsers();
  }
}
```

I registered in router

```
{ path: 'members', component: MemberlistComponent, 
  resolve: { users: MemberListResolver }
},
```

and in app.module.ts:

```
providers: [  MemberListResolver ]
```

and  I call in Component:

```
export class MemberlistComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserService, 
    private alertify: AlertifyService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { 
  }

  users: User[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data['users'];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: In the future, please don't put your regular text in code styling. Move it down 4 spaces.

Comment: Can you show how you are registering `UserService` for dependency injection? Is it with `@Injectable` or as a provider?

Comment: @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  user: User;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users');
  }
  getUser(id): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + id);
  }
} 

in app.module.ts 
providers: [UserService]

Answer (score 0):

there are many reasons could make that happen:

1- it seems you forgot the `@` decorator before the `Injectable` key word in `MemberListResolver`

it should be `@Injectable` not `Injectable`

2- if that's not working too, you need to import this polyfill to the `src/polyfills.ts` file

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

3- If you updated your `Angular` version or `Angular/CLI` version, then remove the `node_modules` and run `npm install`

> note: you don't need to add the `Service` to the `providers` array in the `app.module.ts` as long as you used `{ providedIn: 'root' }`, this will make the same version of this service available in the whole application too
>
> so choose one of the two ways as long as you need to make this instance of the service available application wide

hope this could help